# Why does my filtered image(should be binary) still contain colorful parts?(OpenCV in C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I do difference between two images and compare the result with a "standard" image. By using the command **threshold**, the pixels whose values are below 0 should be black while those with positive values be white. However, after the process the image still contain colorful pixels like red, yellow and so on.

```
threshold(Initial, Final, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

I failed to figure out the origin of colorful pixels, anyone has some ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you grayscale the image first? If you didn't, you will see all sorts of R G B colours in the image once you binarize it.

```
// C
IplImage *im_rgb  = cvLoadImage("image.jpg");
IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im_rgb),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvCvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

// C++
Mat im_rgb  = imread("image.jpg");
Mat im_gray;
cvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

As far as I know it, you have to convert it into grayscale to binarize it to get just Black and White pixels.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold

> The function applies fixed-level thresholding to a single-channel array

so you need to convert your image to grayscale first to get an accurate conversion